# How can I install angular cli compatible with node 13.14.0?

Tags: angular, npm, command-line-interface

I have windows 7, so I tried to install an old version of node: node 13.14.0 But when I tried to install the Angular CLI using this line "npm i -g @angular/cli" I had this error. What can I do? What's the cli version compatible with node 13.14.0? thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: First, it's not good practice to post screenshots of errors, [see here why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). Second, there are just warnings, there is no error. As you can see in the logs, the package was installed successfully. So I don't understand what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install a specific version:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@7.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below links to identify the exact version of angular CLI compatible in your case. It helps me also.

[Angular-AngularCli-Node Compatibility List](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3)

[Angular-TypeScript-Node Compatibility List](https://marco.dev/angular-typescript-node)